# Can I keep my companion's equipment after a storyline death?

Tags: dragon-age-2

During the Deep Roads Expedition, the following event occurs:

> Carver died, taking all of the equipment he had on him.

Do I have any chance for recovering any of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, you do not. You lose everything unless you made sure to unequip them before the event occurs. The [Wikia confirms this](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/The_Deep_Roads_Expedition):

> Note: You will lose all equipment held by either party member, so be sure to take any equipment you'd like to keep from them before leaving.